# Virtual array rotation

Tags: arrays, rotation, virtual

So I need to be able to get specific sections of rotated arrays while preserving the original array.

What I have doesn't work exactly how it should, and I can't tell if it's because of the rotation, or something else.

What I have for the rotation is (in pseudocode):

```
get(x, y, rot%4):
  rot == 1 then arr[height - 1 - y, x]
  rot == 2 then arr[width - 1 - x, height - 1- y]
  rot == 3 then (rot 2, rot 1)
  else arr[x, y]
```

I'm 99% sure that rotating 180 degrees (2) works as intended, but I'm pretty sure I'm messing up 90 degrees, and by extension 270.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured out something correct. Every part of my system was working except this, which is basically the simplest part.

```
get(x, y, rot%4):
  rot == 2 || rot == 3 then
    y = height - 1 - y
    x = width - 1 - x
  rot == 1 || rot == 3 then
    tmp = y
    y = x
    x = height - 1 - tmp
  return arr[x, y]
```

the main advantage to doing this over rotating an entire array is if you only need to grab a tiny amount of values from a rotated version of the array, such as with a 2d "viewportals", or just getting a specific row/column/diagonal, or something of that sort.